# How to handle the loss of elements in queue while reboot in c++

Tags: c++, file, queue

I'm using a queue for storing the values of required elements as given below

```
struct mq{
    mq() : start_time(), end_time(), record_id(), evnt_name(), msg_q_src() {}
    mq(int start_time, int end_time, int record_id, int evnt_name, int msg_q_src) : start_time(start_time), end_time(end_time), record_id(record_id), evnt_name(evnt_name), msg_q_src(msg_q_src) {}
    int start_time;
    int end_time;
    int record_id;
    int evnt_name;
    int msg_q_src;
};
extern mq msg;

extern std::queue<mq> Mqueue;
```

I had found one Possible way to retain the queue without being lost due to reboot

**push the queue to a file before processing**

```
/* Push queue to file */
std::ofstream qoutfile;
qoutfile.open(qfilename,ios::app);
if(qoutfile.is_open()) {
    cout << "opened file " << qfilename << " for writing" << endl;
    qoutfile << Mqueue.front();
    qoutfile << "\n";
    cout << "check cat "<< qfilename << endl;
}else {
    cout << "No File Present";
}
qoutfile.close( );
```

**push the popped queue elements to another file after processing**

```
/*  popped queue to file */
std::ofstream poppedoutfile;
poppedoutfile.open(poppedqfilename,ios::app);
if(poppedoutfile.is_open()) {
    cout << "opened file "<< poppedqfilename << " for writing" << endl;
    poppedoutfile << Mqueue.front();
    poppedoutfile << "\n";
    Mqueue.pop();
    cout << "check cat "<< poppedqfilename << endl;
}else {
    cout << "No File Present "<< endl;
}
poppedoutfile.close( );
```

**after reboot, check the difference between two files and load the lost queue elements and process**

But, is there any other way to handle this scenario ?

Comment: It depends on your usage. I had the exact same problem and since we were using a data base, we just added an entry ‘status’ with a special value when it’s in the queue

Comment: Journaling. Keep a record of what's added and removed to an append-only file. When you boot up again, replay that to figure out where you were. Be sure to OS flush frequently enough, possibly after each transaction.

Comment: doing this robustly is non-trivial, let someone else do the work and use something which does it for you. One option would be a database which are usually designed to survive crashes without losing data, sqlite is quite easy to build into an application